# Firebase exists() vs null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Normally when I check to see if the database contains a node I do something like:

```
users = dbReference.getReference("users").child(someUser);
```

I do not use `hasChild()` because I know on a large dataset this can take sometime to query. However, recently I ran into the method `exists()` [found here on documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()) now I was just wondering how does this differ from me just checking if the snapshot is null? And how does the `exists()` function work? Like `hasChild()` iterates over the dataset what does `esists()` do?

And is it better than checking for null? the documentation doesn't say much

thanks

UPDATE 1

Assuming i have the following node:

[image: example node]

When a user wants to register, I check this node to see if the username is taken:

```
userTakenNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(enteredUsername)) {
                register();
            } 

        }
```

If the username is not taken then I register the user with that username and add the username to the node above. Now I am using hasChild() to my understanding though this will iterate over the whole node till it finds it and will return it else wont return anything. On a large dataset this can take very long.

Is there a quicker way to query the dataset?

Comment: The code you shared sets up a reference to a location in the database. It does *not* check whether a node exists.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I understand the code above I shared is a reference to a database. I was just showing how I would normally get to a child node within the database my question is. assuming the above database reference is null (so doesnt exist in the db) normally to test this I use an if statement and test if dataSnapshot == null. How does the `exists()` function differ from using null to check and which is better to use? thanks

Comment: The database reference you shared will *never* be null. Please update your question to include the minimal, complete code that you're asking about. It'll be a lot easier to help with that.

Comment: please check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely want to only check the specific user name. So attach your listener one level lower in the tree:

```
userTakenNode.child(enteredUsername).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists) {
            register();
        } 
    }
```

But in general this scenario is better suited for a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), which combines getting the current value of the node and setting its new value into a single operation.

Answer (score 1):

exists is slightly more efficient:

> Returns true if this DataSnapshot contains any data. It is slightly more efficient than using snapshot.val() !== null.

[Firebase exists documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists)